# ffmpeg commandline behavior randomness

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to use the *-vf drawtext* functions within ffmpeg.

The following command runs successfully

```
ffmpeg -y -i "C:\2.avi" -preset ultrafast -crf 18 -vf  drawtext=text=stackoverflow:fontfile=C:/WINDOWS/Fonts/georgia.ttf C:\o.mkv
```

However as soon as we alter the command(change positions fontfile= with text=

```
ffmpeg -y -i "C:\2.avi" -preset ultrafast -crf 18 -vf  drawtext=fontfile=C:/WINDOWS/Fonts/georgia.ttf:text=stackoverflow C:\o.mkv
```

I get the following errors

**[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 02d88a80]** *Could not load font "C": impossible to find a matching font*

**[AVFilterGraph @ 02c86a20]** *Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'fontf
ile=C:/WINDOWS/Fonts/georgia.ttf:text=stackoverflow:'
Error opening filters!*

I don't understand why changing the exact same params around can effect the overall outcome, this is causing me real problems because every time I add to this query I have to wonder whether its just the positioning of the params or I am actually doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the path uses a colon (`:`) which also happens to be the separator for arguments. I'd expected that both command lines fail, actually...

The [docs](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Notes-on-filtergraph-escaping) state you'll need to escape colons in general, and also give a particular example for `drawtext`

> Note that the colons need to be escaped.

```
drawtext='fontfile=Linux Libertine O-40\:style=Semibold:text=FFmpeg'
```

So, the following works (Windows is a bit particular on how to escpae stuff in the shell, e.g. no single-quote escaping, so that you need to escape the `\` as well)

```
drawtext=fontfile=C\\:/WINDOWS/Fonts/georgia.ttf:text=stackoverflow
```

Comment: Will test this shortly, seems logically correct. Thanks for pointing that out.

Overall though you would assume if this is the case it would fail whichever order its specified, but it doesnt...